# UPDATE syntax error for SET WHERE LIKE

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE isc_products SET prodretailprice=145 WHERE prodcode LIKE TSACR3
```

I'm trying to update `prodretailprice` for all the products that have `prodcode` "*TSACR3*" but I keep getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[TSACR3]' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `isc_products` SET `prodretailprice`=145 WHERE `prodcode` LIKE 'TSACR3'
```

Enclose the search pattern in single quotes.

`LIKE` syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

`LIKE` can be used with the following wildcard characters

- `%` Matches 0 or more characters. 
   E.g. `LIKE 'TSACR3%'` will match `TSACR3 bla blah`
- `_` Matches exactly one character.
   E.g. `LIKE '_TSACR3'` will match `2TSACR3` but NOT `42TSACR3`

Comment: You should probably also include %s on either side of the TSACR3, as it will only match exactly, instead of matching a larger string.

Comment: @ChrisHenry Thanks, I have updated it with a few words on wild card characters.